# How to validate array form fields in laravel 5.0 using jsvalidator?

Tags: javascript, validation, laravel-5

I have tried many things but no solution is working form me, could you please help me out, how to validate following situation?

Using JsValidator Library
https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation
every other field is being validated, but array fields are not being controlled.

**HTML**

`{!! Form::select('country_id[]', $countries, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'country_id', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}`

```
<!-- Laravel Javascript Validation -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('public/vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js')}}"></script>
{!! JsValidator::formRequest('App\Http\Requests\Admin\CampaignRequest') !!}
```

**FormRequest**

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'PUT':
            $rules = [
                'title' => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:campaigns,id,' . $this->get('id'),
                'description' => 'required',
                'package_id' => 'required',
                'country_id' => 'required',
                'quantity' => 'required',
                'sort' => 'required',
            ];
            break;

        default:
            $rules = [
                'title' => 'required|min:3|max:255|unique:campaigns,id',
                'description' => 'required',
                'package_id' => 'required',
                'country_id' => 'required',
                'quantity' => 'required',
                'sort' => 'required',
            ];
            break;
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide full code of FormRequest?

Comment: I have solved 50% of my problem, I am using JsValidator plugin and described all my code.

Answer (score 0):

If the select is multiple, you don't need write the name as array (country_id instead of country_id[])

```
{!! Form::select('country_id', $countries, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'country_id', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
```

Comment: If I don't write the name as array it won't give me multiple selected fields.